# VS Code Go test coverage highlighting absent

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, code-coverage

I have 2 VS Code workspaces for Go development, in both cases using Go modules.

In the first workspace I get red/green bars in the gutter indicating test code coverage. All very nice.

In the second I cannot get the coverage to show. I know the tests are running (being run by VS Code), using `go test -coverprofile...` and I can check the output and it looks good. I originally had a multi-root workspace but I tried creating a new one with just a single root for the module I'm working on. I tried making sure the root path did not include symlinks.

I have spent several hours now looking at the differences between the settings at user, workspace and folder level for the two workspaces and cannot find any differences.

I would appreciate and suggestion on how to track down why the coverage highlighting is not showing.

I'm using go 1.13.15.

**Update**

I have updated to VSCode 1.51.1 and go 1.15.2. No change.

However, when I use a git diff then I do see the coverage in the gutter, just not in normal editor views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue - I migrated from dev machine #1 to dev machine #2, and had the exact same environment, software/tools versions, etc. Code coverage worked as expected on dev1, but not on dev2.

The critical difference was that, on dev2, I connected to a vscode workspace that was a symlink of my gopath, whereas on dev1, that path had been a proper directory. When I connected to my vscode workspace on dev2 to the underlying directory, and *not* the symlinked version, code coverage began to display correctly.

Comment: A little irritating to have to avoid the symlink, in my case in the path to the workspace, but it is all working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
go test -v -cover ./...
```

The above code shows the coverage in terminal, to show coverage highlighting in vs code I did the following

```
ctrl + shift + P
```

then search **Go: Toggle Test Coverage in Current Package** and hit enter. Then check.

Comment: yo this works fine.